# Accumulation point of a filter is the limit of some superfilter

Tags: general-topology, filters

After proving that the accumulation point of an ultrafilter is its limit and that every filter is contained in an ultrafilter (using Zorn's lemma) the author asks us to prove that an accumulation point of a filter is a limit of some superfilter. How it follows from the above two isn't obvious to me since I don't see how being the accumulation point of a filter implies being the accumulation point of the ultrafilter containing it. I proved it as follows :

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a filter with an accumulation point $x$. Then for each neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and each $F\in\mathscr{F}$ we got $F\cap U\neq\emptyset$. But this would imply that $\mathscr{F}\cup\mathscr{N}_x$ (where $\mathscr{N}_x$ is the neighbourhood filter at $x$) has finite intersection property, and thus extends to (without any application of Zorn's lemma) a filter $\mathscr{G}$. Since $\mathscr{N}_x\subset\mathscr{G}$ by definition $\mathscr{G}\rightarrow x$.

I don't seem to have applied Zorn's lemma in the above. Also, how did the author expect us to prove it?

Comment: any thoughts would be appreciated too

Comment: What is your definition of *superfilter*? The only definition that I’ve seen is that it’s a family $\mathscr{S}$ of subsets of $X$ closed under taking supersets and such that if $A\cup B=S\in\mathscr{S}$, then $A\in\mathscr{S}$ or $B\in\mathscr{S}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott It being the opposite of subfilter i.e. a filter containing the given filter

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the author had the idea that an accumulation point of a filter is also one for a superfilter but this is false: it holds for limits, but not for accumulation points. (just like a subsequence of a convergent sequence is still convergent, but an accumulation point of a sequence need not be one for a subsequence of it. The fact you have to show (and did correctly, essentially) is the analogue to the fact that an accumulation point of a sequence is the limit of some subsequence (in metric spaces e.g.). The key observation is indeed that $\mathcal{N}_x \cup \mathcal{F}$ has the f.i.p. and thus extends to a filter $\mathcal{G}$, say.

But we *do* need Zorn to extend that $\mathcal{G}$ to an ultrafilter (that still converges to $x$ of course). So because the statement explicitly asks for an ultrafilter we need the Zorn lemma fact..

Comment: But I don't need an ultrafilter just a superfilter.

Comment: Also, I noticed this: Accumulation point of a subsequence (subnet) is also an accumulation point of the sequence (net) but the converse is not true. A limit of the sequence (net) is also a limit of its subsequence but the converse is not true. In the case of filters, the roles are exactly reversed.

Comment: @HritRoy then you don’t need it.